# Причина пробуждения экрана

Tags: android

Прослушиваю ресивером пробуждение экрана. Можно ли узнать из за чего пробудился экран?(Пользователь нажал на кнопку разблокировки, или же какая то программа (скайп, будильник и т.п.))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать реализовать некий слушатель, который включается в момент пробуждения (перехвата бродкаста):

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(MAX_PRIORITY); 
 for(int i=0; i < taskInfo.size(); i++)
    String activityName = taskInfo.get(i).topActivity.getClassName();
```

и посмотреть что находится в стеке менеджеров активити, последний или предпоследний это очевидно будет таск, который сгенерировал бродкаст.

**P.S.** Нужен пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: Неплохое решение. Интересно, можно как то прослушать изменение этих тасков? Или же например узнать открылся или закрылся какой нибудь таск?